# Compile a .NET2.0 DLL from .NET4.0

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I am using .NET4.0, but for compatability reasons, I'd like to compile to a .NET2.0 dll from c#. There should be no .NET4.0 specific functionality used in the script, so it should run fine in a .NET2.0 environment. Is there some commandline syntax on the csc that I can specify a version number with?

Comment: I believe you can specify that as your build target in the project properties.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx

Comment: Are you saying you want to install a .Net 2.0 dll on a machine that ONLY has .Net 4.0 installed?  Or would .Net 2/3/3.5 also be installed?

Comment: @Brook: .NET 4.0 is [backward compatible anyway](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939.aspx) (as long as you don't do anything too exotic).

Comment: @Robert: Right but if 2.0 is also installed, an easy way to do it would be to just invoke the 2.0 version of csc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mentioned `csc.exe`, so I'm assuming that you won't be building with Visual Studio, but rather, by command line. Also, I'm assuming that `msbuild` is not available on the build machine.

I believe that `csc.exe` is specific to each version. For example, in the folder `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319`, you will find `csc.exe`, and in the folder `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727`, you will find another version of `csc.exe`.

To build a .NET 2.0 dll, you should reference the `csc.exe` from the v2.0 folder (`C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727`).

Cheers!

Comment: Terrific. Thank you. I didn't realize there were multiple frameworks installed on the system.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio you could set the target framework version to .NET 2.0 in the properties of the project:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

if you are compiling manually from the command line, can't you just run the v2 framework csc?

eg (paths from my machine)

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\csc.exe
```

or for v4

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

If you build with MSBuild (which of course includes from within VS) then you can specify the target framework version from the project properties dialog. However, if you build manually it seems [there is no surefire way to express that restriction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146155/targeting-specific-frawework-version-in-csc-exe).

Answer (score 0):

Set the target framework to 2.0 in the project's properties. In case you are using features like LINQ that are not present on the 2.0 framework, this approach won't work. If you need full compatibility with 2.0 framework, you should write your code for the 2.0 and then compile targeting the 4.0 later if you need.