# Building a module in C# for Powershell 2 without Visual Studio or access to an SDK

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, dll

I'm trying to build a module in C# for Powershell 2.0 on a machine where I don't have administrator permissions and no tools installed explicitly for building. I've got almost everything I think I'd need to make this work, but I'm botching the `csc` call somehow.

My [Powershell version is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1825807/1028230):

```
PS C:\temp\> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
2      0      -1     -1
```

To get the `System.Management.Automation dll` out of the CAC, I followed [this brilliant advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13485939/1028230):

```
Copy ([PSObject].Assembly.Location) C:\temp
```

To build with `csc`, I'm trying to follow [this advice from Mr. Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/146167/1028230):

> In addition to this, you can use /noconfig /nostdlib and then
>   explicitly reference the .NET 2.0 assemblies (in
>   c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727 for example). It looks
>   like the /lib command line option can make this slightly easier by
>   letting you specify a directory to look in for references, but I
>   haven't tried that myself.

Here's my current command line:

```
csc /out:shims.dll /target:library /noconfig /nostdlib /lib:c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727 /r:..\System.Management.Automation.dll;System.dll;mscorlib.dll PowershellPlay.cs
```

That builds fine, but when I try to import the module, I get that I'm using too new a version of the framework -- which, of course, is what I was trying to avoid with the /lib, /nostdlib, and /noconfig settings.

```
Import-Module : Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\temp\PowerCLI_1\shi
ms.dll' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer t
han the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.
At line:1 char:14
+ Import-Module <<<<  .\shims.dll
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Import-Module], BadImageForma
   tException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.BadImageFormatException,Microsoft.PowerSh
   ell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

Wonder if I have to change which csc I use?  Doesn't seem like that should be a requirement/matter.

```
c:\temp>where csc
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe
```

---

**EDIT:** Okay, I think I've got the answer: I'm doing things in my code that aren't .NET 2.0 kosher.  **I'm a little surprised the 2.0 version of csc seems to compile it, though.  ??**

Anyhow, the below **works**:

Code for cmdlet:

```
using System;
using System.Management.Automation;

[Cmdlet("Test", "PowershellCompilation")]
public class Test : Cmdlet
{
    [Parameter]
    public string Server = "";

    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        WriteObject(this.Server + "test");
    }
}
```

`csc` call:

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\csc /out:test.dll /target:library /r:..\System.Management.Automation.dll Test.cs`

I've got that call in a bat file named `buildTest.bat`.

```
PS C:\temp\PowerCLI_1> .\buildTest.bat

C:\temp\PowerCLI_1>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\csc /out:test
.dll /target:library /r:..\System.Management.Automation.dll Test.cs
Microsoft (R) Visual C# 2005 Compiler version 8.00.50727.5483
for Microsoft (R) Windows (R) 2005 Framework version 2.0.50727
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2001-2005. All rights reserved.

PS C:\temp\PowerCLI_1> Import-Module .\test.dll
PS C:\temp\PowerCLI_1> Test-PowershellCompilation
test
PS C:\temp\PowerCLI_1> Test-PowershellCompilation -Server spam
spamtest
PS C:\temp\PowerCLI_1>
```

Note that I was unable to get the 4.0 version of `csc` to work using a command like this:

`csc /out:test.dll /target:library /noconfig /nostdlib /lib:c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727 /r:..\System.Management.Automation.dll;System.dll;mscorlib.dll Test.cs`

That gave the "runtime newer" error again.

So success.  I'll try to convince Eris to turn the comment into an answer; if I'd tried the 2.0 version of csc first, I wouldn't've tried the "compile for 2 with csc for 4" madness.

Comment: @sepp2k (realizing he probably won't see this) I see where you're coming from, but I got the compiler tag following [this question's lead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/146155/targeting-specific-frawework-version-in-csc-exe?lq=1). If that's not fair, fine, but 1.) a comment why is probably helpful & 2.) I'm going to add `compiler-construction` one more time just in case the other question's tagging wasn't illegitimate (note that I did add it in an edit; I was waffling on its use).

Comment: Try using `[Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeEnvironment]::GetRuntimeDirectory()`\csc.exe instead of the default? When I check the RuntimeDirectory on powershell -version 2, it shows ...Framework64\v2.0.50727

Comment: @Eris Ultimately, I think that's the right answer -- to build for 2.0, you need to use the `csc` for 2.0.  Knowing that, it's easier to track down that the problem must be my code using stuff from > 2.0.  Not sure why `csc` from 2.0 compiles it, but there you go. If you want to make your comment an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: BTW: you could just use Add-Type -OutputAssembly? It would do the same under the hood I think, but would prevent you from shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: @BartekB Yeah, I think you're right. I did wonder why I'd talked myself out of that. Been reading Bruce Payette's *Windows Powershell in Action*, and he goes `Add-Type` a good bit. There was something about "dynamic binary modules" that sounded squirrelly -- they don't compile to dlls, right?  I'll take another look.

Comment: @ruffin That question was mistagged as well. Neither question has anything to do with how compilers are constructed, so they shouldn't have the compiler-construction tag.

Comment: Depending on how complex the code is, `Add-Type` supports inline C# also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
[Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeEnvironment]::GetRuntimeDirectory()\csc.exe
```

PowerShell v2 uses the framework in ...Framework64\v2.0.50727